# dynamic pl/sql syntax package proc

Tags: oracle, plsql

syntax trouble with a simple dyanamic pl/sql insert statement. my code is as follows.

```
sql_stmt     VARCHAR2(500);

sql_stmt := 'PKG_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_INS_01(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)';
execute immediate sql_stmt using 
        IN OUT V_P1, 
        IN OUT V_P2, 
        IN OUT V_P3, 
        IN OUT V_P4, 
        IN OUT V_P5, 
        IN OUT V_P6;
```

(error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement)

What should the actual syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change this part to make it into PL/SQL instead of SQL:

```
sql_stmt := 'begin PKG_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_INS_01(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6); end;';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the executed statement is not dynamic, I strongly suggest you don't use *execute immediate*. Instead, I'd go with a simple

```
PKG_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_INS_01(V_P1,V_P2,V_P3,V_P4,V_P5,V_P6);
```

which achieves the same thing, but is cleaner and results in an invalid procedure/package/function if the signature of `PKG_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_INS_01` changes.